# How to take 1-x/100 of entire pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to calculate 1-x/100 for an entire pandas series? How can I do that?

x is the values in a dataframe series consisting of float numbers.

Comment: What happened when you tried anything? Also, there's no inversion going on here.

Comment: @mehmet_Soydam do accept and upvote the answer you found most helpful it motivates the community

Answer (score 1):

This can be done simply

```
1-(pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])/100)
#replace pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5]) with df['coumn_name'] your required series
```

output:

```
0    0.99
1    0.98
2    0.97
3    0.96
4    0.95
```

Do mention an example of current and desired outcomes u need and always mention code to reproduce example, do keep in mind these point for your next questions

Comment: really appreciate it thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a new Series as the result, as follows:

```
df['result'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: (1-x)/100)
```

If this is not what you want, you need to clarify what you tried and what is your expected output in the question.

Comment: Yes, this worked well. Thanks!

Comment: yeas apply must be rarely used only in very complex customised cases when vectorization is not possible. If at you want to run this code on series with millions of rows it wont let you do your thing fast.

Comment: It is not neccessary